# How to fix the error No serializer found for class java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, serialization, resttemplate

In java, I am trying to access a Spring Boot Microservice using the following code:

```
try {   
        CircularsSaveParams circularsSaveParams;
        circularsSaveParams= new CircularsSaveParams( request,  principal,  session, locale,  mav,souqBean); //creating microservice params


        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(circularsSaveParams,headers);

        ResponseEntity<Boolean> responseEntity =    restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8084/circular-save", HttpMethod.POST, entity, Boolean.class);

        //String employeeDivision= restTemplate.getForObject("http://employee-division-service/"+id+d, String.class);
        status= responseEntity.getBody();


    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here, the fields of the class `CircularsSaveParams`seems to cause the problem. Below is that class,

```
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import ae.gov.adm.saeed.bean.CircularsBean;


public class CircularsSaveParams {

    HttpServletRequest request; 
    Principal principal;
    HttpSession session;
    Locale locale; 
    ModelAndView mav;
    CircularsBean souqBean;

    public CircularsSaveParams()
    {


    }


    public CircularsSaveParams(HttpServletRequest request, Principal principal, HttpSession session, Locale locale,
            ModelAndView mav, CircularsBean souqBean) {
        super();
        this.request = request;
        this.principal = principal;
        this.session = session;
        this.locale = locale;
        this.mav = mav;
        this.souqBean = souqBean;
    }

    public HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
        return request;
    }
    public void setRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }
    public Principal getPrincipal() {
        return principal;
    }
    public void setPrincipal(Principal principal) {
        this.principal = principal;
    }
    public HttpSession getSession() {
        return session;
    }
    public void setSession(HttpSession session) {
        this.session = session;
    }
    public Locale getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }
    public void setLocale(Locale locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }
    public ModelAndView getMav() {
        return mav;
    }
    public void setMav(ModelAndView mav) {
        this.mav = mav;
    }
    public CircularsBean getSouqBean() {
        return souqBean;
    }
    public void setSouqBean(CircularsBean souqBean) {
        this.souqBean = souqBean;
    }



}
```

When I run the code, I get the following error on this line,

```
  ResponseEntity<Boolean> responseEntity =    restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8084/circular-save", HttpMethod.POST, entity, Boolean.class);
```

Below is the stack trace.

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: ae.gov.adm.saeed.params.CircularsSaveParams["request"]->org.springframework.web.multipart.support.DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest["request"]->ae.gov.adm.saeed.web.security.AuthFilterHttpServletRequestWrapper["request"]->org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade["servletContext"]->org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade["classLoader"]->org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader["resources"]->org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot["context"]->org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext["logger"]->org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog["logger"]->java.util.logging.Logger["parent"]->java.util.logging.Logger["parent"]->java.util.logging.Logger["parent"]->java.util.logging.Logger["parent"]->java.util.logging.RootLogger["handlers"]->java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler["formatter"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:293)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:539)
    at ae.gov.adm.saeed.web.controller.util.CircularsControllerUtil.saveCircularView(CircularsControllerUtil.java:357)
    at ae.gov.adm.saeed.web.controller.CircularsController.saveCircular(CircularsController.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at ae.gov.adm.saeed.web.security.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:335)
    at ae.gov.adm.saeed.web.security.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:610)
    at ae.gov.adm.common.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:417)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: ae.gov.adm.saeed.params.CircularsSaveParams["request"]->org.springframework.web.multipart.support.DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest["request"]->ae.gov.adm.saeed.web.security.AuthFilterHttpServletRequestWrapper["request"]->org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade["servletContext"]->org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade["classLoader"]->org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader["resources"]->org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot["context"]->org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext["logger"]->org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog["logger"]->java.util.logging.Logger["parent"]->java.util.logging.Logger["parent"]->java.util.logging.Logger["parent"]->java.util.logging.Logger["parent"]->java.util.logging.RootLogger["handlers"]->java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler["formatter"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:26)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:663)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ObjectArraySerializer.serializeContents(ObjectArraySerializer.java:241)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ObjectArraySerializer.serialize(ObjectArraySerializer.java:201)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ObjectArraySerializer.serialize(ObjectArraySerializer.java:25)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:663)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:663)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:663)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:663)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:663)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:663)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:663)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:663)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:663)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:663)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:663)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:663)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:663)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:663)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:851)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:286)
```

Please note that I have the below method defined:

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = 
        new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper);
    return converter;
}
```

How to fix the problem?

**Update:** I have tried to define my object like this, after some research:

```
circularsSaveParams= mapper.convertValue(new CircularsSaveParams( request,  principal,  session, locale,  mav,souqBean), CircularsSaveParams.class); //creating microservice params
```

However, the problem was not solved. Same error appears.

**Edit** Here's how the server code looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/circular-save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public Boolean saveCircularView(@RequestBody  CircularsSaveParams circularsSaveParams) {


    System.out.println( "circular-save microservice Called..................................");

    HttpServletRequest request= circularsSaveParams.getRequest();
    Principal principal= circularsSaveParams.getPrincipal();
    HttpSession session= circularsSaveParams.getSession();
    Locale locale = circularsSaveParams.getLocale();
    CircularsBean souqBean = circularsSaveParams.getSouqBean();

    boolean status = false;
    boolean isModifyRequest = false;
    GmCirculars gmCircular = null;
    try {

        if(null!=souqBean.getCircularEntryId() && !BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(souqBean.getCircularEntryId())) {
            gmCircular = circularsService.findById(souqBean.getCircularEntryId());
            isModifyRequest = true;
        }

        gmCircular = souqBean.populateCircularEntity(gmCircular);
        ApplicationUser applicationUser = getLoggedInUser(request, principal);
        gmCircular.setOrganization(applicationUser.getOrganization());

        //LOG.info("Ajax Call to Save Circular [" + gmCircular + "]");

        if(!isModifyRequest) {
            gmCircular.setCreatedBy(applicationUser);
            gmCircular.setCreatedOn(new Date());
        }
        if(souqBean.getShowOnDashboard() == null)
            gmCircular.setShowOnDashboard(new BigDecimal(0));

        GmCirculars savedObj = circularsService.saveOrUpdate(gmCircular);

        if(null!=savedObj && null != savedObj.getId() && !BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(savedObj.getId())) {   
            status = true;
        }
        else {
            status = false;
        }

      String externaDoclId=null;
        //Saving Attachment 
        MultipartFile fileDataIcon = souqBean.getCircularAttachment();
        if (null != savedObj && null != savedObj.getId() && !BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(savedObj.getId())) {

            if (null != fileDataIcon && fileDataIcon.getSize() > 0) {

                Documents uploadedDoc = uploadMuFile(request, fileDataIcon, principal, savedObj.getId(), ModuleEnums.GM_CIRCULARS,null);

                if (uploadedDoc != null && uploadedDoc.getId() != null) {
                    savedObj.setDocumentId(uploadedDoc.getId()); //Modified BY ZAID ZAID ZAID ZAID ZAID ZAID
                    savedObj = circularsService.saveOrUpdate(gmCircular);
                    status = true;

                    externaDoclId=uploadedDoc.getExternalDocumentId();
                }
                else {
                    status = false;
                }
            }
            else { // without doc
                status = true;
            }

            if(status) {
                saveUserActivityLog(applicationUser, ModuleEnums.GM_CIRCULARS.getValue(), savedObj.getId(), 
                    isModifyRequest ? ActionTypeEnums.EDIT.getValue() : ActionTypeEnums.ADD.getValue());
            }
        }





    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        status = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    System.out.println("circulars save microservice is DONE!........................................status is:"+status);
    return status;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but why are you serializing framework classes request, mav and all ? You could just send your request body and let the server handle all the sessions and other things.

Comment: I am actually seperating a huge monolithic software into microservices and need to make them communicate while sending parameters like those. It is not fixed requirements of course but the server microservice needs to access such objects to achieve the task.

Comment: All these framework objects will be created and injected in the server microservice just like they got injected in your calling microservice. All you have to send is your pojo  that you would need on server side. In your case it would be just CircularsBean. Could you show how your server endpoint looks like ?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help. I edited the question to show how it will look like on the server side. It will use all these parameters I am sending.

Comment: Are you saying that if I didn't pass these parameters, the server won't complain that they weren't sent with json request headers?

Comment: You should not be serializing log formatters or loggers at all, or anything much at all beyond mere POJOs. Something is seriously wrong here.

Comment: Okay. Loggers are not needed. But how do you suggest I get these objects that are essential for the task, given they are not POJOs?

Comment: Session and locale object you are not using anywhere so those are not required, request and principal object you are using to identify the user. I hope you can inject this two objects in the class containing "saveCircularView" method. No need to serialize these objects and pass them to post call.

Comment: When you are separating a Service into microservices, these are different applications that need to communicate with eachother. You CAN NOT send internal Spring beans via JSON. There is a lot of state behind that. These are not simple objects, what you are trying to do is simply an approach that can't work. You have to separate the code on the level of business logic. Maybe try to explain what you are actually trying to achieve and what the services are supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking it incorrectly. You can't and you shouldn't share requests between applications. You should use some service user or some oauth generated tokens to communicate with other restful micro services as oppose to passing user principal over. You can always pull in the user from db if you have a unique way to identify user like some sequence number.

If you trying to move your backend services to another microservices you should only send the information that is needed for backend and have the calling microservice take care of authentication/authorization and user sessions/auditing.

From your server implementation it looks like you are tracking who/what request is made to the microservice. This can be tracked in calling microservices before you sent the request. If you many such microservices you could create a central proxy (another microservice) which takes care of logging/auditing user requests before routing to called microservice.

Comment: You are also right in your first comment to this question. In Spring, the request and other framework objects doesn't need to be passed to the microservice. Based on my experiment. The microservice has access to them automatically, and it was surprising to me, given that they are in another project. In fact, I did not need to pass any object to the microservice, and it had already these fields populated! Perhaps, it is spring magic.