# Why Spring Boot Microservice has the parameter Principal with null value, and how to get the actual value that the client application has?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, principal

In Spring Boot, I have the following microservice, which needs the Principal object, in order to access logged in user info:

```
        @RequestMapping(value="/circular-save")
        public Boolean saveCircularView(HttpServletRequest request, Principal principal, HttpSession session, Locale locale, ModelAndView mav,
                @ModelAttribute CircularsBean souqBean) {


            System.out.println( "circular-save microservice Called...........principal="+principal);

            //some user related code here that depends on principal
    }
```

Output:

```
circular-save microservice Called.....................principal=null
```

I call the above microservice as the following:

```
System.out.println("Will call circulars with principal:"+principal.getName());
restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/circular-save", Boolean.class);
```

Output:

```
Will call circulars with principal:travelling.salesman
```

As you can see, the principal value is not null on the client side, but it is null on the server side. How to correctly have this principal object passed between microservices?

My research:

At first, I was considering passing it in json request and using POST method, but I failed because it's not a POJO and it will not be possible to serialize it.

I did more research, and found this line that could be written on the server side.

```
principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

Unfortunately, the above solution gave me different object that resulted in having anonymous user that is different that the original user.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Is principal a request parameter ? Also , you are doing an `http.get`

Comment: @R.G, I am not sure if it's called request parameter but it comes along with other parameters such as request and session in Spring. Yes I am using http.get, what is the problem with that?

Comment: With `get` one need to pass parameters in the URI . [Refer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#getForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.util.Map-) . I would suggest you attempt a post as in this [example](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/resttemplate/spring-restful-client-resttemplate-example/)

Comment: Also the principal returned with `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` is the logged in user

Comment: @R.G. I tried POST earlier with exchange method but I got error: self reference leading to cycle, and I was recommended based on many developers not to pass such objects as parameters because they are not simple objects and cannot be serialized. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60392915/how-to-fix-the-error-no-serializer-found-for-class-java-util-logging-simpleforma/60490390#60490390

Also, I tried this line but I did not get the logged in user on the server side, rather anonymous user.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your requirement correctly. On a successful authentication ( login ) , the principal is assocaited with the request. Is you webapp secured? Are you sending any header parameter for login ?

Comment: The app itself has the value of the principal correct, and it returns the logged in user, but when it communicates with the microservice, the principal on that end is null, and I am not passing it anyway. How do I get it there is my question. Please check my question as I explained things there simply. I do not know what do you mean by secure, but I have the following configuration:  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

Comment: The microservice is another webapp. The principal will be available only when you successfully authenticate the request . JWT is one way to achieve this . [example](https://medium.com/@mool.smreeti/microservices-with-spring-boot-authentication-with-jwt-and-spring-security-6e10155d9db0)

Comment: I will have a look. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @R.G, if possible, can you please post an example for how to use JWT in my code above, in order to make the principal available?

Comment: Please refer this [example](https://github.com/in28minutes/full-stack-with-angular-and-spring-boot/tree/master/restful-web-services/src/main/java/com/in28minutes/rest/webservices/restfulwebservices/jwt). With JWT,  when you request the other microservice with the token , the [Filter](https://github.com/in28minutes/full-stack-with-angular-and-spring-boot/blob/master/restful-web-services/src/main/java/com/in28minutes/rest/webservices/restfulwebservices/jwt/JwtTokenAuthorizationOncePerRequestFilter.java) in the second webapp will authenticate the token and set the principal.